# Handling checked checkboxes jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a scenario of 3 checkboxes and table with few rows.

Let's say checkboxes chk_1, chk_2 and chk_3.
P.S: chk_1 is checked by default.

The condition that I require is:

1. If chk_1 checked -> display table row A only
2. If chk_2 checked -> display table row A only
3. If chk_3 checked -> display table row B only
4. If chk_1 and chk_2 checked -> display table row A only
5. If chk_1 and chk_3 checked -> display table row A and B both
6. If chk_2 and chk_3 checked -> display table row A and B both
7. If chk_1, chk_2 and chk_3 checked -> display table row A and B both.

   $('.calculator_container').hide();
   $('.angelpricingtable').css('display', 'none');
   $('.equity_tr').css('display', 'none');
   $('.commodity_tr').css('display', 'none');
   var chk_1 = $('#equity_check').prop("checked");
   var chk_2 = $('#derivative_check').prop("checked");
   var chk_3 = $('#commodity_check').prop("checked");

   if (chk_1 == true && chk_2 == true && chk_3 == true) {
   $('.calculator_container').show();
   $('.angelpricingtable').css('display', 'table');
   $('.equity_tr').css('display', 'table-row');
   $('.commodity_tr').css('display', 'table-row');
   }

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
var chk_1 = $('#chk_1').prop("checked");
var chk_2 = $('#chk_2').prop("checked");
var chk_3 = $('#chk_3').prop("checked");


if(chk_1 == true && chk_2 == true && chk_3 == true){
    //If chk_1, chk_2 and chk_3 checked -> display table row A and B both
}
else if(chk_1 == false && chk_2 == true && chk_3 == true){
    //If chk_1 and chk_2 checked -> display table row A only 
}
else if(chk_1 == true && chk_2 == false && chk_3 == true){
    //If chk_1 and chk_3 checked -> display table row A and B both
}
else if(chk_1 == true && chk_2 == true && chk_3 == false){
    //If chk_2 and chk_3 checked -> display table row A and B both
}
else if(chk_1 == false && chk_2 == false && chk_3 == true){
    //If chk_3 checked -> display table row B only
}
else if(chk_1 == false && chk_2 == true && chk_3 == false){
    //If chk_2 checked -> display table row A only
}
else if(chk_1 == true && chk_2 == false && chk_3 == false){
    //If chk_1 checked -> display table row A only
}
```

Comment: Hey!! Thanks. Will get it checked and respond back. :)

Comment: Hey Bro this doesn't seem to work. Let me know what I am doing wrong. Updated my question with my code.

Comment: console the values of 
var chk_1 = $('#equity_check').prop("checked"); 
var chk_2 = $('#derivative_check').prop("checked"); 
var chk_3 = $('#commodity_check').prop("checked");